# Which Pseudo-Random Number Generator to use in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, random, prng

C++11 comes with a set of PRNG's.

In what situation should one choose one over another? What are their advantages, disadvantages etc.

Comment: Not for C++11, but boost::random has many of the same choices, so this might help http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/random/random-generators.html

Comment: I've seen three questions about RNG's on the front page today. What is going on?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the **Mersenne twister `std::mt19937`** engine is just fine as the "default" PRNG.

You can just use **`std::random_device`** to get a non-deterministic seed for `mt19937`.

There is a very interesting talk from GoingNative 2013 by *Stephan T. Lavavej*:

> [`rand()` Considered Harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

You can download the slides as well from that web site. In particular, slide #23 clearly compares `mt19937` vs. `random_device`:

> - `mt19937` is:
>
>   - **Fast** (499 MB/s = 6.5 cycles/byte for me)
>   - Extremely high quality, but *not* cryptographically secure
>   - Seedable (with more than 32 bits if you want)
>   - Reproducible (Standard-mandated algorithm)
> - `random_device` is:
>
>   - Possibly slow (1.93 MB/s = 1683 cycles/byte for me)
>   - Strongly platform-dependent (GCC 4.8 can use IVB RDRAND)
>   - Possibly crypto-secure (check documentation, true for VC)
>   - Non-seedable, non-reproducible

Comment: That is fine, but he does not compare the speed of mt19937 with another PRNG. Also, sometimes it is nice to have constraints instead of absolute algorithms. This makes the code perform better in the future.

So what about (The actual type behind these should be implementation defined)

typedef random_device cryptographic_random_generator; 
typedef mt19937 simulation_random_generator; //Strictly more accurate than fast_random_generator
typedef linear_congruential_engine<some well behaving parameters> fast_random_generator; //At least as fast as simulation_random_generator

Answer (score 1):

The trade-off is speed, memory foot-print and period of PRNG.

1. Linear Congruential Generators: fast, low memory, small period
2. Lagged Fibonacci(Subtract with Carry): fast, large memory, large period
3. Mersenne Twister: slow, very large memory, very large period

Comment: To avoid being misleading, "very large memory" is still very small; it's only large in comparison to the other options. Sort of like comparing pebbles to grains of sand when you have a whole sandbox to play in.

Comment: @Hurkyl One must never compare quantities that measure different things. If the grain size is important on its own, the hole sandbox does not count.

Comment: LCGs can have a very long period depending on state size.  A 128-bit LCG is still fast, low memory, and has a very long period.